# Is it me or is the favicon shimmering?

Tags: discussion

You know, the logo on the tabs. It starts to shimmer and look a bit more green for tabs on the main page when left too long. Is this an intentional design change? Or am I just sleep-deprived?

Answer (score 1):

It's just you.  I just checked the file and it's really just a static bitmap, not an animated icon.  Only one icon in the file too.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's intentional, you're just sleep-deprived ;-)

Comment: alright. High time I went to bed then.